# How do I handle "negative" hours as a result of my subtraction?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 cells, formatted as Excel *Time*:

```
A1= 1:00 AM
B1= 2:00
C1: B1-A1
```

I want to subtract B1 to A1, and expect result to be

```
 C1= 11:00 PM
```

Can anyone explain why I'm not getting this? With my (undisclosed) Excel release, I get:

> ```
> -1:00AM
> ```

I have tried many forms and there is a problem  anyways.

Comment: Show what you've tried and what the result were.

Comment: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/06/24/calculate-time-excel/#excel-negative-time

Comment: You cannot have (-1:00AM) as there is no such thing as negative time in a worksheet.

Comment: Sorry, we're not getting the same "-1:00AM" as you do. Maybe you have some Excel-vba behind your Excel sheet that do the calculation? What is your Excel release? Carefully read our http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Answer (score 1):

Use,

```
=a1-b1+(b1>a1)
```

Format as `h:mm AM/PM`.

[image: time_subtraction]

Comment: Like it! But it will not work if you substract more than 24 hours. =A1-B1+((B1>A1)*1000) would be more robust.

Comment: That is going to produce a datetime (typically circa Sep-1902), not a time.